# Showing percentage symbol in ArcGIS map labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, labeling

I'm trying to show percentage poverty per municipality on the map I'm working on, and I have the percentage values displayed on the map, but I don't know how to get the percentage symbol itself to show.

I've already tried to format labels and clicked 'number represents a percentage', so under labels it shows that the values are in percentages, but doesn't display that on the map.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well. The two answers given to this question are instructions on how to turn the data into percents. But the OP says "so under labels it shows that the values are in percentages, but doesn't display that on the map." So our issue is not changing the values into percents, the labels are now formatted as percents. That's not the problem. The problem is the actual numbers "80%" "90%" don't show up on the map. They instead show up as circles or squares or whatever based on the percent size. So to reiterate one more time, how do we get the actual numbers to appear on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your Layer Properties and to the Labels tab.  Click on "Expression" and then set it up so it displays the field that contains your percentage followed by a & "%".  The whole thing will look like this:

```
[Field] & "%"
```

When you go back to your map, your labels should show the number followed by a percentage sign.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, open your attribute table and right-click on the field heading for your value and choose Properties. Click the Number Format ... button and choose percentage. You'll have to make the appropriate choices as to whether your number is already a percent and possibly additional choices under Numeric Options.  Once that's done, your values should label with the % sign in the attribute table as well as in any labels using that field.